# Are all Infinity Gems of the same size?

Tags: marvel, comics, infinity-stones

[The Infinity Gauntlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_Gauntlet) was designed to hold the six [Infinity Gems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Gems) (or the six soul gems as they are known in some universes). It's sole purpose was to act as a holder to unify the Infinity Gems.

There have been several depictions of the Infinity gauntlet with all the six the gems. Some depict all gems with the same size while the others show five gems with the same size and the sixth gem (at the center) being larger than the others.

So, are all the Infinity Gems of the same size (and what I saw simply was the artist's choice) or are the gems of varying sizes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Originally intended to be the same size

The official marvel wiki at marvel.com has the following to say on the physical appearance of the gems.

> Small oval gems approximately one inch in length; each one has a specific color: Time [Orange-Red], Space [Purple], Mind [Blue], Reality [Yellow], Power [Red-Pink], and Soul [Green].
> <sub>[Marvel.com - Infinity Gems](http://marvel.com/universe/Infinity_Gems)</sub>

In an early appearance together on the Infinity Gauntlet, they were the same size ([Infinity Gauntlet #1](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet_Vol_1_1)):

[image: Infinity gauntlet]
<sub>[Full cover for above screenshot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/af/Infinity_Gauntlet_1.jpg)</sub>

Note: In their first appearance on the gauntlet ([Silver Surfer Vol 3 #44](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Silver_Surfer_Vol_3_44)) they were all the same size.

It would seem that if the gems are represented in different sizes in different issues it is up to the discretion of the author how they choose to represent them. However, Marvel seems insistent that they were each oval shaped about an inch in length and of a similar/identical size.

Due to some doubt I have found some more images showcasing their near identical size. [1](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/e/e3/Thanos_%28Earth-616%29_from_Thanos_Quest_Vol_1_2_0001.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20161011031953), [2](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/b/b8/Thanos_%28Earth-616%29_from_Thanos_Quest_Vol_1_1_001.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180422065001), [3](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/4/49/Erik_Stevens_%28Earth-TRN662%29_from_Marvel_Contest_of_Champions_001.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180219061646), [4](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/e/ec/Infinity_Gauntlet_%28Item%29_from_New_Avengers_Vol_3_3_001.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20151013053043), and a whole other set of images can be found [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Infinity_Gems/Images).

### Other universes

#### Earth-199999

The stone on the back of the hand is clearly larger than the four on the finger knuckles, the one on the thumb knuckle might be larger as well, although that is unclear.

[image: MCU Infinity gauntlet]

#### Earth-1610

There are 8 infinity stones, all of which are the same size, as seen by the four on the left hand glove.

[image: Earth-1610 Infinity gauntlet]

Comment: They're not actually the same size in your first image. It's hard to see whether it's due to perspective or not.

Comment: @OrangeDog while they're not 100% identical, they are meant to be the exact same size. As highlighted by the comment that goes with it. It's the artists interpretation of the 3-D curve of the hand.

Comment: Being "all approximately one inch" is not the same as "the exact same size".

Comment: @OrangeDog well that depends on your understanding of the phrase. They could all be the same size of approximately 1 inch (i.e. there is no exact canonical length but it's close to one inch and they're all that size) or that they're not necessarily the same size but they're all around the length of one inch. So yes it can be the same, and in the context is, but doesn't _need_ to be.

Comment: Where is the context that makes it mean that they are all exactly the same? You keep saying they're meant to be the same, but have no proof.

Comment: I've provided plenty of evidence, the pixel density of the stones might not be identical but they are intended to be identical. If you are so convinced that they are not I welcome you to write your own answer proving them as such, until then, good day, sir.

Comment: "they are intended to be identical", "they are meant to be the exact same size" - how do you know? You have provided a lot of evidence showing that they're always drawn in a variety of sizes, but not a single source or proof that anyone intended them to be the same.

Comment: @OrangeDog I've explained to you the source, it comes from the quote on the marvel wiki, which you seem to be misinterpreting. There is no exact canonical size of the stones. They are _all_ approximately an inch. They are all the same or very similar size, and the size is around an inch. Whether they are 100% identical or 1mm less or a 1/32" less makes no difference to the matter of the question. They're intended to be the same size, there perspective alters how similar they look in size. When they are in fact _different sizes_ they are _vastly_ different.

Comment: You are the one misinterpreting the quote. 0.7" and 1.4" are both "approximately one inch" and yet one is twice the size of the other.

Comment: @OrangeDog I've linked 4 images that show they're identical size, and another whole collection that show many more images showing identical size, similar sized and differently sized gems.

Comment: OK, in image 1 they are actually identically sized (and colored). In 2 and 3 though they are vastly different. Image 3 even has the massive central gem.

Comment: Of course, this could be up to the aesthetic sense of the *wielder*; if you hold all the gems, I don't see why you couldn't alter their actual or apparent size.

Comment: And, it's not clear that the Infinity Stones in the post-*Secret Wars* Marvel U will be the same size (noting I haven't read the *Infinity Countdown* books as yet). The one "gem" that had been found, last I saw, was several times larger than a human being....

Answer (score 3):

According to the wikia page on the [Infinity Gauntlet](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet_(Item)) the very first appearance of the item was in *Silver Surfer Vol. 3 Issue 44* published in December 1990. The gauntlet and stones appear in this comic a few times and in every shot the stones appear to be the same size.

[image: Silver Surfer Vol. 3 Issue 44, page 6]

[image: Silver Surfer Vol. 3 Issue 44, page 26]

Comment: But they're not actually the size in those images (especially the second). It's hard to see whether it's due to perspective or not.

Comment: @OrangeDog To me they look the same size but perspective does throw it off a bit

Comment: On my screen the green one is 9mm while the blue is 8mm. They should be the same distance to the "camera".

Comment: @OrangeDog I think you're being difficult on purpose but that can be down to an error in the drawing, perspective or even close enough that the difference is negligible. However, the question is are they the same size, not are they exactly the same size.

Comment: I'm not being difficult. It just struck me that they are clearly different sizes in that image (the pinky-gem is tiny). For all we know that's the one the question is talking about.

Comment: Interestingly, the only images I've seen (from 616) of them all being the same are the ones where they're also all green.